# "set number" in .vimrc not working in Vim for iOS

Tags: ios, vim

I added the following .vimrc file to the home directory of Vim for iOS on my iPad.

```
set showcmd
set number
set guifont=Courier:h24
imap jk <Esc>
```

For some mysterious reason, all commands work fine except `set number`. Since manually typing `:set number` still works, it can't be that Vim for iOS doesn't support displaying line numbers. I have no clue why it behaves differently when I put it in .vimrc. Any ideas?

Comment: Do the other settings work? If they do maybe some plugin is overwriting the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with

```
:verbose set number?
```

where this got set last.

If that doesn't provide a hint, capture a log with `vim -V20vimlog` and check for `:set number` commands. (This assumes that you can launch Vim on the command-line on the iPad. If not, add `:set verbose=20 verbosefile=vimlog` to your `~/.vimrc`.)

Also, the `:scriptnames` command shows all scripts that ran after your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: I tried `:verbose set number?` and got `nonumber`. Not sure what that means, but seems like `:set nu` never worked in the first place. But something weird happened after that. Instead of using iTunes to import .vimrc from a PC, I directly wrote a new .vimrc in Vim for iOS...and voilà! Everything works now. Guess it was something about the iTunes transfer process. Still scratching my head as to what exactly happened though.

Comment: Hm, with Windows-style line endings, you should have gotten errors in Vim. Maybe it wasn't readable at all. Anyway, I'm glad you've figured it out!

Comment: By "Windows-style line endings", do you mean that Windows uses a different newline character from Vim? I've never thought about that. (I used notepad on Windows to write the original .vimrc)

Comment: Windows Vim understands both the native CR-LF as well as Unix-style LF, but Unix Vim barks on the former. This is important when sharing a .vimrc across different platforms.

Answer (score -1):

`echo 'set nu' >> ~/.vimrc`